# How to pass nginx HTTP status codes (in access logs) to php.

Tags: php, laravel, http, nginx, web

I am trying to find the time when the client closes the browser connection(499 HTTP status). I can see those in nginx access logs, but I dont know how to access that from php.

Comment: You should use (preferably) a search engine + cron job (for indexing) which indexes data from logs, ex:ElasticSearch. There is a php library for this https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-php

Comment: but connection is not closed when your php code is being processed. It is only when it sends response, which in turn is sent to client, the connection is closed, how can you access that before it being generated?

Answer (score 0):

You have to parse your nginx access logs file with PHP script and run it with cron or run like daemon.

**Here's the example:**

```
<?php

$handle = fopen("/path/to/your/access.log", "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
      if(strstr($line, 'HTTP/1.1" 499')){
        echo $line;
      }
    }

    fclose($handle);
} else {
    // error opening the file.
}

?>
```

Make sure current script has a permission for reading access log file.